# How to group by and sum several columns?

Tags: pandas, sum

I have a big dataframe with several columns which contains strings, numbers, etc. I am trying to group by SCENARIO and then sum only the columns between 2020 and 2050. The only thing I have got so far is sum one column as displayed as follows, but I need to change this '2050' by the columns between 2020 and 2050, for instance.

```
df1 = df.groupby(["SCENARIO"])['2050'].sum().sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Try this `df1 = df.iloc[:,[2020:2050]].groupby(["SCENARIO"]).sum().sum(axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a subset of the df with only that single column. I can't tell how your dataset looks like from the information provided, but try:

```
df.groupby(["SCENARIO"]).sum()
```

This should some up all the rows which are in the column.

Alternatively select the columns which you want to perform the summation on.

```
df.groupby(["SCENARIO"])[["column1","column2"]].sum()
```